# Macros in C.... please give the solution

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose I declared a macro name anything, `xyz()`.

Now I am creating another macro `xyz1()` and reference the 1st macro i.e `xyz()` in 2nd.

Finally, I'll create another macro `xyz2()` and reference the 2nd macro in 3rd.

Now my question is: is this correct (it's executing without any problem)?
Macro `xyz()` is defined twice. Why its not giving an error? What is the solution?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible hack of some sort... on behalf of whoever has to maintain your code later, please don't do this...

Comment: Show some code please. From the description, it sounds like you are only declaring `xyz` once.

Comment: why is `xyz` defined twice? according to your description, you are creating once `xyz`, once `xyz1` and once `xyz2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, the first macro wiil only be defined once. When you write

```
#define Symbol SymbolResolution
```

the preprocessor will substitute `Symbol` for `SymbolResolution` wherever it sees `Symbol`. If `SymbolResolution` is a `#define`, or includes some symbols that have `#define`s inside the same will happen to them - they will all be replaced. This will happen until there're no symbols that have `#define`s for them in the whole translation unit.

So you can reference macros from other macros as you wish. You can't however reference macros recursively. You also should be careful with this - this can easily lead to lots of barely readable and very hard to debug code if you misuse macros.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean macros referencing other macros, It is legal.

> When the preprocessor expands a macro
>   name, the macro's expansion replaces
>   the macro invocation, then the
>   expansion is examined for more macros
>   to expand.

```
#define hello() (12)
#define test() (1+hello())
```

However a macro calling itself is not legal

> A self-referential macro is one whose
>   name appears in its definition. Recall
>   that all macro definitions are
>   rescanned for more macros to replace.
>   If the self-reference were considered
>   a use of the macro, it would produce
>   an infinitely large expansion. To
>   prevent this, the self-reference is
>   not considered a macro call.

Comment: also, you can't define (and have it working) `#define make_macro(x) #define macro_ ## x  funcname ## x()` (the embedded define will not be evaluated).